# Can this areca palm be saved and if so how would I do it?

Tags: diseases, watering, repotting, palm

Is my areca palm completely dead or can I save it somehow? All the leaves are dry and either brown or faded green, and the stems have black spots. Please refer to the photograph.

[image: enter image description here[![1]]

Answer (score 1):

If the central growing point is dead (not possible to see from your image) ,then its a goner; if you can see any green when you look down into the palm,especially in the centre, there's a chance it's still alive.

Answer (score 0):

I still see some yellow, which is not as good as green, but better than all brown. What was the problem, lack of water? Then give it more. Palms like quick draining soil -- think sand not mud. Palms react slowly, so don't expect quick results.